# Missing lint - npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I homebrew upgrade to the latest node. When I git commit, I got this following error.

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.1.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/7.2.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "run" "lint"
npm ERR! node v7.2.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.9

npm ERR! missing script: lint
```

Comment: So, is there any problem? I don't see any question being asked.

Answer (score 0):

oolong

Turns out to be added a new dependency caused a pre-commit forced check.